# Same Salt, Different Encrypted Password is not working? Using Linq to update password

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am running into a wall regarding changing the password and was wondering if anyone had any ideas.  Here are the database values prior to changing the password:

```
Clear Text password = abc1980
Encrypted Password = Yn1N5l+4AUqkOM3WYO7ww/sCN+o=
Salt = 82qVIhUIoblBRIRvFSZ1fw==
```

After I change my password to abc1973,  salt remains the same, but the Encrypted Password changes which is supposed to happen:

```
Encrypted Password = rHtjLq3qxAl/7T1GfkxrsHzPsNk=
```

However, when I try to login with abc1973 as the password, it does not login.  If I try abc1980, it logs me in.  It is updating the database, is it caching the values somewhere?

Any ideas?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to receive useful answers.

Comment: SLaks, glad to provide more info, what in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it right after I posted this.  I stopped and started the Application Pool in IIS and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

please read this and heed the advice contained therein:

http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence

If you have fixed your problem by restarting the Application Pool, I would encourage you to understand exactly how that fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very nice.